# redux saga take() returns undefined after dipatching an action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

So to be short , the take effect of redux saga returns object which rpoperies are undefined except the type . Here is my saga `

```
import axios from 'axios';

import {
  take, put, call
} from 'redux-saga/effects';

import {
  getEventInfo, GET_EVENT_INFO
} from '../actions';

export default function* eventInfoSaga() {
  try {
    const { token, query } = yield take(GET_EVENT_INFO);
    console.log(token, 'token'); // undefined
    console.log(query, 'query'); // undefined
    const options = {
      method: 'post',
      url: `https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?q=${query}&expand=venue`,
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    };
    const response = yield call(axios, options);
    console.log(response, 'response eventInfoSaga');
    yield put(getEventInfo(response));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

This is makeActionCreator`

```
const makeActionCreator = (type, ...argNames) => (...args) => {
  const action = { type };
  argNames.forEach((arg, index) => {
    action[arg] = args[index];
  });
  console.log(action, 'actioooooooooooon');
  return action;
};

export default makeActionCreator;
```

which i call with this `

```
import { makeActionCreator } from '../utilities';

export const GET_EVENT_INFO = 'GET_EVENT_INFO';
export const getEventInfo = makeActionCreator(GET_EVENT_INFO, 'token', 'query');
```

And this is the component where i dispatch an action with parameters `

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import SearchIcon from '../SvgIcons';
import MapComponent from '../Map';
import { getEventInfo, getUserInfo } from '../../actions';

class DashboardPage extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatchUserInfo } = this.props;
    dispatchUserInfo();
  }

  handleEventSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { dispatchEventInfo } = this.props;
    const query = e.target.children[0].value;
    console.log(query, 'queryyyyyyyy'); 
    **dispatchEventInfo(query, query);**
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props, 'proooops');
    return (
      <div className="dashboard-container">
        <div className="search-event">
          <form className="search-event__form" onSubmit={this.handleEventSearch}>
            <input
              autoComplete="off"
              type="text"
              name="search-event"
              placeholder="Search an event"
              className="search-event__input"
              aria-label="Enter search text"
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
            <button type="submit" className="search-event__button">
              <SearchIcon />
              Search
            </button>
          </form>
          <p className="sign-out">
            <a href="/api/logout" className="btn btn--sign-out sign-out__button">Sign out</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="google-map">
          <MapComponent
            isMarkerShown
            googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAGCyELoQaEHdu5GWT5WPTYU-T811MA4SY&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
            loadingElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
            containerElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
            mapElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

DashboardPage.defaultProps = {
  dispatchUserInfo: null,
  dispatchEventInfo: null,
};

DashboardPage.propTypes = {
  dispatchUserInfo: PropTypes.func,
  dispatchEventInfo: PropTypes.func
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const name = state.userReducer.name || '';
  const accessToken = state.userReducer.accessToken || '';
  return {
    name,
    accessToken
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  dispatchEventInfo() {
    dispatch(getEventInfo());
  },
  dispatchUserInfo() {
    dispatch(getUserInfo());
  }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DashboardPage);
```

In redux-saga documentation they say that take(pattern) Creates an Effect description that instructs the middleware to wait for a specified action on the Store. The Generator is suspended until an action that matches pattern is dispatched.As i understand **yield** will make it wait that specific action and then do something (request, change, etc.).
So why i am getting undefined ? May be i misunderstand something

Comment: Have you tried having a function to take the action and call another to execute?
Like:
export default function* eventInfoSaga() { 
yield take([GET_EVENT_INFO], anotherfunc); 
}
function * anotherfunc(action) { do here what you want }

Comment: Yes, the same result

Comment: Perhaps you should simplify your makeActionCreator by removing (...args)?
Now I think when you call it, it returns a function, and you would like to return the action?

Comment: makeActionCreator is just making an action creator  which then when invoked will dispatch an action. I know this is complicated , but not wrong

Comment: If you log args inside makeActionCreator you see an empty array, so you should check how you call it, because you are not passing anything. Or use argNames if that suits you..

Comment: I found my problem . Ahhh , so frustrated , i am just very tired to make that error . I didn't pass parameters that function in mapDispatchToProps . Thank you very much , when you wrote **empty array** i guessed the problem )